# How to handle "make this better" questions when the asker has little or no GM restrictions and has a lot of chosen options?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question asks for help improving a custom item: [Is this armor the best my character can get?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203635)  They have already chosen 9 rules elements to add to the item. It will be difficult to think of a better way to improve the item. As it stands, the item will not be bound by wealth by level restrictions, gold cost, or combining features that require GM fiat.

Am I missing something? Doesn't this make the question difficult to answer? Or should someone take a stab at trying to improve it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you asking if the question should be closed?

Comment: I don't think it's answerable, well short of "seems good". So I guess I think it needs more focus, yes.

Comment: They just updated the question, I'll get a chance to read it tonight and see if it's easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Difficulty is not a criterion for closure.

You'll notice that when you vote to close or flag for "needs improvement", "question is too difficult" is not one of the reasons offered. Our site is one of the better places on the internet to ask difficult questions. We have lots of experts in lots of different games. Answering difficult questions is one of the things we're good at.

#### This question has many of the key features of a good optimization question.

Now, about this specific question, I will admit, *I am not an expert in D&D 3.5e*. However, I do have a bit of experience on the site, and it seems to me that this question has several of the key features of a good optimization question. Reading through, the question provides:

- Campaign setting details
- Ground rules for building the item
- Relevant rules in place at the table
- Character build details
- Permitted and non-permitted sourcebooks
- A first attempt at optimization ("show your work")
- Areas where that first attempt might be improved

Overall, this question provides extensive background details, expectations for the build, rules for the table and setting, and even a first attempt that answers may use as a starting point. This question provides far more detail than we typically see from optimization questions, and its objectives seem clear enough to me. I think the question is fine. But of course, I should hedge this with the reminder than I am not a 3.5e expert, so I may be missing crucial system knowledge that invalidates my analysis here, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I have indeed tried to make the question as answerable as possible by adding in the details you list, some of which were suggested in comments and some of which I knew from experience using this site. If anyone with the system knowledge you're lacing wants to point out somehting more, I'm all ears.